# Фильтрация данных в DataGridView с помощью LINQ

Tags: c#, winforms, linq

Есть пустой `DataGridView`который привязан к источнику данных, и настроен на отображения двух столбцов `Id` и `Name`.

Нужно отфильтровать данные, по запросу введенным в `TextBox`.

Фильтрацию делаю с помощью

```
var selected = db.Products.Where(p => p.Name.ToString().StartsWith(textBox1.Text)).OrderBy(p => p.Name);

foreach (var item in selected)
{
    dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value = item.Id;
    dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value = item.Name;   
}
```

`i` - счетчик строк, но когда он равен `1`, происходит ошибка "Индекс за приделами диапазона".

Добавлять строку с помощью метода `Rows.Add()` тоже не получается, программно нельзя добавить строки в Grid с привязкой данных.

Такой способ работает если Grid не привязан к данным. Мне надо работать с привязкой данных.

Comment: Можно просто обновить источник данных...`dataGridView1.DataSource = selected.ToArray();`

Comment: @Ev_Hyper, ваш вариант работает как надо, оформляйте как ответ! 
Я с ним не сразу разобрался как использовать, вот добил вечером его.

Comment: Готово. В следующий раз просто уточните, если что-то будет не понятно :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно просто обновлять источник данных:

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = selected.ToArray();
```

Answer (score -1):

Скорее, нужно приводить не к Array, a к списку - `ToList();`.